# Analogs of Intel's Cluster OpenMP

Tags: openmp, shared-memory, cluster-computing, distributed-system

Are there analogs of Intel Cluster OpenMP? This library simulates shared-memory machine (like SMP or NUMA) while running on distributed memory machine (like Ethernet-connected cluster of PC's).

This library allows to start openmp programs directly on cluster.

I search for

- libraries, which allow multithreaded programms run on distributed cluster
- or libraries (replacement of e.g. libgomp), which allow OpenMP programms run on distributed cluster
- or compilers, capable of generating cluster code from openmp programms, besides Intel C++

Answer (score 3):

The keyword you want to be searching for is "distributed shared memory"; there's a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory) on the subject.  MOSIX, which became openMOSIX, which is now being developed as part of [LinuxPMI](http://linuxpmi.org/trac/), is the closest thing I'm aware of; but I don't have much experience with the current LinuxPMI project.

One thing you need to be aware of is that none of these systems work especially well, performance-wise.  (Maybe a more optimistic way of saying it is that it's a tribute to the developers that these things work at all).   You can't just abstract away the fact that accessing on-node memory is very very different from memory on some other node over a network.  Even making local memory systems fast is difficult and requires a lot of hardware; you can't just hope that a little bit of software will hide the fact that you're now doing things over a network.

The performance ramifications are especially important when you consider that OpenMP programs you might want to run are almost always going to be written assuming that memory accesses are local and thus cheap, because, well, that's what OpenMP is for.    False sharing is bad enough when you're talking about different sockets accessing a common cache line - page-based false sharing across a network is just disasterous.

Now, it could well be that you have a very simple program with very little actual shared state, and a distributed shared memory system wouldn't be so bad -- but in that case I've got to think you'd be better off in the long run just migrating the problem away from a shared-memory-based model like OpenMP towards something that'll work better in a cluster environment anyway.

Comment: LinuxPMI/MOSIX is not what I need. They simulate a single computer using a several and they do a whole-process migrations to balance load. The Intel Cluster OpenMP allows me to easily (add one option to compiler) switch from single-node openmp to multi-node openmp. Rewriting of programm to MPI is not so easy.

Comment: For accessing a non-local memory in Intel ClusterOpenMP the caching is used. So, repeated accesses will be fast. Library takes care of memory coherency. Without falseshaing and with repeated accesses programms will be rather fast

Comment: +1: I agree with @Jonathan Dursi (I usually do).  I think that @osgx is being optimistic in believing that any shared-memory-program-on-distributed-memory-hardware will deliver satisfactory performance.  As the great Dr Johnson said, in another context "It is not done well; but you are surprised to find it done at all."